# How to Add Affected CIs to Problem Ticket in ServiceNow With pysnow

Tags: python, servicenow

I'm trying to add "Affected CIs" to a problem ticket in ServiceNow:

[image]

Using some python automation, I'm able to create several tickets using the following:

```
import pysnow

snow = pysnow.Client(instance=instance, user=username, password=password, raise_on_empty=True)
snow.table = 'problem'

affected_ci = 'jbj9842jm'

payload = {'short_description':ticket.title,
            'description':ticket.verbiage,
            'assignment_group':last_rec['support_group'],
            'assigned_to':last_rec['support_group_manager'],
            'u_root_cause':ticket.root_cause,
            'u_vulnerability_type':ticket.v_type,
            'u_vulnerability_criticality':ticket.v_criticality,
            'urgency':ticket.v_urgency,
            'impact':ticket.v_impact,
            'u_problem_notes':'Affected CIs\n'+affected_ci
            }

res = snow.insert(table='problem', payload=payload)

print("Support Group: "+payload['assignment_group']+" has been assigned ticket number: "+res['number'])
```

But, to this point, I have only been able to add "Affected CIs" as problem notes `'u_problem_notes':'Affected CIs\n'+affected_ci`.

I know the "Affected CIs" table is a table attached to the problem ticket record. What I don't know is how to add an item (or items) to this table.

Seeing as the problem ticket is contained in the "problem" table, I thought I might access it by using the request from the original `insert` to get the problem ticket number, then add that to the table path and insert a CI there:

```
ci = payload['u_problem_notes'].split()
for i in range(1, len(ci)):
    ci_payload = {'task_ci':ci[i]}
    snow.insert(table='problem/'+res['number'], payload=ci_payload)
```

That yielded the following:

```
pysnow.legacy_exceptions.UnexpectedResponse: Unexpected HTTP POST response code. Expected 201, got 405
```

How do I add "Affected CIs" to a ServiceNow problem ticket using pysnow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The "Affected CIs" table is actually the `task_ci` table in ServiceNow.  To post a record to it, you need to provide the `sys_id` of both the CI you're trying to add, and the PRB ticket you're submitting it to.

To get the CI `sys_id`, you need to query whatever table your company uses to store configuration items, in my case the `cmdb_ci` table.

Using the same pysnow client as above, you can create two more "resources", which are REST API call wrappers that point to the appropriate tables:

```
q_ci = snow.resource(api_path='/table/cmdb_ci')
t_ci = snow.resource(api_path='/table/task_ci')
```

Then loop through your list of CIs to first check that they exists in the CMDB, then add them to the `task_ci` table:

```
    # Look up CIs in CMDB and add to the Affected CI table for each PRB ticket
    for ci in ci_list: # List of CI hostnames
        try:
            # Ask CMDB if hostname exists
            ci_info = q_ci.get(query={'name': ci})
            if ci_info == '':
                raise ValueError
            # If it does, create a task_id record for that PRB ticket
            # With 'res' being the response from the PRB ticket insert call
            t_ci.create({'ci_item':ci_info['sys_id'], 'task':res['sys_id']})
        except:
            # Otherwise, make a note of unknown hostnames
            not_found_in_cmdb.append({'ci_name':ci, 'for_prb':res['number']})
            continue
```